# How to not show the stdout output of a running process?

Tags: process, stdout

When a running process gives lots of stdout output throughout its lengthy running process, you don't want to kill it and rerun it. How can you not show the output? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.hackers/0ZMsMc5DvUw

Comment: @jimmij i have read through material you provided . i think the script mentioned is almost good but there is a portion i do not agree with . anyway let me write an answer here .

Answer (score 4):

One approach could be to attach a debugger to the process and make it open stdout on /dev/null:

```
gdb --batch -ex 'call close(1)' -ex 'call open("/dev/null",2)' -p "$pid"
```

Comment: Interesting. (1) first Ctrl-z to suspend it before running `gdb`? (2) Is `call` a command in gdb? Are `close` and `open` also?

Comment: @Tim please see my answer .

Comment: Does the `2` in the call to `open` signify `O_RDWR`?

Answer (score 1):

let me yank here the solution @jimmij pointed to , with minor modification .

```
(gdb) attach <pid>    
... 
(gdb) call open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY)
$1 = 3
(gdb) call dup2($1,fileno(stdout))
$2 = 1
(gdb) call close($1)
...
(gdb) detach
...
```

for those not familiar with gdb , "attach" "call" "detach" are gdb commands . get information with "help attach" inside a gdb prompt . and "open" "dup2" "close" are library functions . get information with "man 2 open" .

here O_WRONLY equals 1 and fileno(stdout) equals 1 . use literal values or gdb may complain lack of symbols .

---

and if we want to find a file descriptor already opened , we can .

```
$ cd /proc/<pid>/fd
$ for i in * ; do
          if [[ `readlink $i` == "/dev/null" ]]
                  fd=$i ; break
          fi
  done
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be stdout and not stdin?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen fixed .

Answer (score -1):

The following will prevent normal returns as well as error messages

```
2&>1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: The OP asks about an *already* running process.